# :before grey background-color appearing as white in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am using `:before` on a div with a the background-color `#f2f1ef`. It works fine in Safari, Firefox, Edge, IE11 but the background-color is appearing as white in Chrome browser.

[image: Screen shot]

When I inspect the element it is computing the correct background-color but appearing as white? Also, If I change the hex code to another color it works?

```css
.bullet-container:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 17%;
 background-color: #f2f1ef;
}
```

```html
<div class="bullet-container">
    Content Goes Here
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In the future, please create a runnable snippet that demonstrates the problem - you can do that directly in your question editor, or you can use a site like jsFiddle.

Comment: Works properly in Chrome and Firefox.  (FYI, your screenshot is not helpful at all, it's impossible to know / tell which part you think should be gray in that screenshot).  I'm guessing there's some other styles at play that are conflicting / causing the problem.

Comment: The snippet above works fine Chrome. What are the styles for `.bullet-container`? does it have `position: relative;`?

Comment: @cale_b Sorry if I wasn't clear. Thanks for the tip. I was using a filter on the container which was causing the problem. I thought I had checked that but apparently not. Thanks again!